Are you OK with the site participating in the Winter Bash?
As moderators, we have to decide whether to make the site participate in the Winter Bash this year. It's a short fun period where "hats" are awarded to users, which they then wear on their avatar. Last year, we participated. 
Details about the event of this year aren't yet available, apparently, but you can read everything on last year's blog here:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/
Please do vote the answers below, we have to provide a response by 1 Dec.
UPDATE: I just filled the form and submitted our yes. Thanks to all the ones who answered this poll.

YES, I definitely want the site to participate!

No, please, we are serious people.

I love the -1 here :P!
